# Python: static variable decorator

Tags: python, variables, static, namespaces, decorator

I'd like to create a decorator like below, but I can't seem to think of an implementation that works. I'm starting to think it's not possible, but thought I would ask you guys first.

I realize there's various other ways to create static variables in Python, but I find those ways ugly. I'd really like to use the below syntax, if possible.

```
@static(x=0)
def f():
    x += 1
    print x

f() #prints 1
f() #prints 2
```

I don't care if the implementation of `static` is long or hackity, as long as it works like above.

I created this version, but it only allows a `<function>.<varname>` syntax, which gets cumbersome pretty quickly with longer function and variable names.

```
def static(**assignments):
    def decorate(func):
        for var, val in assignments.items():
            setattr(func, var, val)
        return func
    return decorate
```

Various things I thought of, but couldn't get to work were:

1. Changing f (the decorated function) into a callable class, and somehow storing the static vars in `self` transparently.
2. Modifying the globals of f() inside the decorator, and somehow inserting 'global x' statements into the code for f.
3. Changing f into a generator where we bind the variables by hand and then execute f's code directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a decorator that seems to work.
Note that this requires return locals() at the end of the function due to being unable to set locals from the outside (I don't have much experience programming so if there is a way, I don't know it).

```
class Static(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, f):
        def wrapped_f():
            try:
                new_kwargs = {}
                for key in self.kwargs:
                    i = getattr(f, key)
                    new_kwargs[key] = i
                self.kwargs = new_kwargs
            except:
                pass
            for key, value in f(**self.kwargs).items():
                setattr(f, key, value)
        return wrapped_f

@Static(x=0, y=5, z='...')
def f(x, y, z):
    x += 1
    y += 5
    print x, y, z
    return locals()
```

The output would be:

```
>>> f()
1 10 ...
>>> f()
2 15 ...
>>> f()
3 20 ...
```

EDIT:

I found something at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410698/ and decided to try adding it to this. It works without the return now.

EDIT again: Changed to to make it a few seconds faster.
Edit 3; changed to function instead of class

```
def static(**kwargs):
    def wrap_f(function):
        def probeFunc(frame, event, arg):
            if event == 'call':
                frame.f_locals.update(kwargs)
                frame.f_globals.update(kwargs)
            elif event == 'return':
                for key in kwargs:
                    kwargs[key] = frame.f_locals[key]
                sys.settrace(None)
            return probeFunc
        def traced():
            sys.settrace(probeFunc)
            function()
        return traced
    return wrap_f
```

tested:

```
@static(x=1)
def f():
    x += 1

global_x = 1
def test_non_static():
    global global_x
    global_x += 1


print 'Timeit static function: %s' % timeit.timeit(f)
print 'Timeit global variable: %s' % timeit.timeit(test_non_static)
```

output:

```
Timeit static function: 5.10412869535
Timeit global variable: 0.242917510783
```

Using settrace slows it down quite drastically.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty close, but I'd like to remove the requirement of returning locals(), if possible. 

Can anyone improve this one?

Comment: Wow that's pretty darn close! 

Could you edit the answer to remove the arguments, like you suggested? Then that would answer my question exactly.

We can work on making it fast and pretty after it works.

Answer (score 9):

By the time your decorator gets the function object `f`, it's already been compiled -- specifically, it's been compiled with the knowledge that `x` is local (because it's assigned with the `+=` assignment), the normal optimization (in `2.*` you can defeat the optimization, at a staggering price in performance, by starting `f` with `exec ''`; in `2.*`, you cannot defeat the optimization).  Essentially, to use the syntax you crave, you have to recompile `f` (by recovering its sources, if you know they'll be available at runtime, or, much harder, by bytecode hacks) with somehow-modified sources -- once you've decided to go that way, the simplest approach is probably to change `x` into `f.x` throughout the body of `f`.

Personally, if and when I find myself fighting so hard against the language (or other technology) that I'm trying to bend to my will to impose my desires, I acknowledge that I'm either using the wrong language (or other technology), if those desires are absolutely crucial, and then the solution must be to change technology; or, if those desires are not that crucial, give up on them.

Either way, I give up trying to distort the language too far away from its obvious design intentions: even if I did come up with some hacky, fragile kludge, it would no doubt be unmaintainable. In this case, Python's desire intentions are very clear: barenames that get re-bound within a functions are locals of that function unless explicitly designated as globals -- period. So, your attempt to make barenames (that get re-bound within a function) mean something completely different than "locals" is exactly this kind of fight.

**Edit**: If you're willing to give up on the insistence on using **barenames** for your "statics", then suddenly you're not fighting against Python any more, but rather "going with the grain" of the language (despite the design glitch of `global` [and `nonlocal`], but, that's a separate rant;-).  So, for example:

```
class _StaticStuff(object):
  _static_stack = []
  def push(self, d):
    self._static_stack.append(d)
  def pop(self):
    self._static_stack.pop()
  def __getattr__(self, n):
    return self._static_stack[-1][n]
  def __setattr__(self, n, v):
    self._static_stack[-1][n] = v
import __builtin__
__builtin__.static = _StaticStuff()

def with_static(**variables):
  def dowrap(f):
    def wrapper(*a, **k):
      static.push(variables)
      try: return f(*a, **k)
      finally: static.pop()
    return wrapper
  return dowrap

@with_static(x=0)
def f():
    static.x += 1
    print static.x

f()
f()
```

This works just like you desire, printing 1 and then 2.  (I'm using `__builtin__` to make it simplest to use `with_static` to decorate functions living in any module whatsoever, of course).  You could have several different implementations, but the key point of any **good** implementation is that "static variables" will be **qualified** names, **not** barenames -- making it explicit that they're not local variables, playing with the grain of the language, and so forth.  (Similar built-in containers, and qualified names based on them, *should* have been used in Python's design, instead of the `global` and `nonlocal` design glitches, to indicate other kinds of variables that aren't local ones and therefore should not be using barenames... ah well, you can implement yourself a `globvar` special container on the same lines of the above `static` ones, without even needing decoration, though I'm not so sure that is entirely feasible for the `nonlocal` case [perhaps *with* some decoration and the tiniest amount of black magic...;=)]).

**Edit**: a comments points out that the code as given doesn't work when you only decorate a function that returns a closure (instead of decorating the closure itself). That's right: of course, you have to decorate the specific function that uses the `static` (and there can be only one, by definition of function-`static` variables!), not a random function that doesn't in fact use the `static` but rather just happens to be in some lexical connection with the one that *does*.  For example:

```
def f():
  @with_static(x=0)
  def g():
    static.x += 1
    print static.x
  return g

x = f()
x()
x()
```

this works, while moving the decorator to `f` instead of `g` doesn't (and couldn't possibly).

If the actual desiderata are not about static variables (visible and usable only within a single function) but some hybrid thing that's usable throughout a certain peculiar bundle of functions, that needs to be specified very precisely (and no doubt implemented very differently, depending on what the actual specs **are**) -- and ideally that needs to happen in a new and separate SO questions, because this one (which is specifically about *static* instead), and this answer to this specific question, are already plenty big enough.

Comment: I agree, but my hope is that this kludge/hack wouldn't be necessary indefinitely. My aim was to either demonstrate that this is or isn't possible. I'd like to someday use this question as either an initial implementation or the counter-example for a PEP. I'm not sure I agree with your evaluation of design intentions, since "nonlocal" variables are in python3. nonlocal is tantalizingly similar, yet disappointingly not very usable as C-style static variables. (python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104) Maybe someone can meet the challenge by using python3.0? 

...I can't seem to insert paragraphs.

Comment: @buzkor, I know the design intentions pretty well as I was one of the parties debating them as they were formed (though the final decision is Guido's). `nonlocal` is just one more variant of `global` (I don't like either, I think they sit athwart most of Python's otherwise pretty-consistent design, and using a special keyword from which to make qualified names would have been much better -- but clearly I lost that debate in terms of Guido's final decisions). I may edit my answer to show how that would work.

Comment: @buzkor, edited my answer to show how everything becomes smooth and solid as soon as you give up on the craving for barenames meaning things other than local variables -- a really unreasonable demand, no matter the design glitches of global and nonlocal. Namespaces are one honking great idea, let's do more of those: using qualified names means I _am_ doing one more namespace, rather than striving to shoehorn into an existing namespace (the one used for local variables, i.e. barenames) stuff that doesn't _belong_ there. No downside, all upside, all Pythonic, smooth, and sweet.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: This solution fails if `f` returns a closure.

Comment: @Anand: works fine with closure or anything else as long of course as the decorator wraps whatever function is actually using statics!

Comment: @AlexMartelli I just noticed that you contrast 2.* with 2.*, which doesn't make sense. I believe you mean 3.* in the second case?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a really simple solution that works just like normal python static variables.

```
def static(**kwargs):
  def wrap(f):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
      setattr(f, key, value)
    return f
  return wrap
```

Example usage:

```
@static(a=0)
def foo(x):
  foo.a += 1
  return x+foo.a

foo(1)  # => 2
foo(2)  # => 4
foo(14) # => 17
```

This more closely matches the normal way of doing python static variables

```
def foo(x):
  foo.a += 1
  return x+foo.a
foo.a = 10
```

Comment: Guess this is no longer valid since the question has been changed to include this solution, but points out that this becomes cumbersome with long function names.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that (but I haven't tested this extensively; used CPython 2.6):

```
import types

def static(**dict):
    def doWrap(func):
        scope = func.func_globals
        scope.update(dict)
        return types.FunctionType(func.func_code, scope)
    return doWrap

# if foo() prints 43, then it's wrong
x = 42

@static(x = 0)
def foo():
   global x
   x += 1
   print(x)

foo() # => 1
foo() # => 2
```

It requires declaring those variables as global and shadows top-level global variables, but otherwise should work. Not sure about performance, though.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, without decorators?

```
class State(dict):
    """Object interface to dict."""
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError, name

def f(d=State(x=0)):
    d.x += 1
    return d.x
```

And here is it in action:

```
>>> f()
1
>>> f()
2
>>> f()
3
```

Comment: A mis-informed user could start trying to use that argument and break the function. In this case we're creating an argument that's never intended to be used as an argument. I do realize that this is a fairly standard practice in python, but I don't think it should be. That's the true aim of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might be much clearer.  It doesn't involve any decorators or hacking.

```
class F( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.x= 0
    def __call__( self ):
        self.x += 1
        print self.x

f= F()
```

Now you have your function `f` with a static variable.

```
f() #prints 1
f() #prints 2
```

Comment: This works by not using barenames -- the problem is entirely with the desire of using _barenames that get modified inside a function_ as anything else than locals of that function (unless the function explicitly designates them as global); there's no problem doing so with qualified names (such as `self.x` or anything else that's _not_ a barename).

Comment: @Alex Martelli: While true that the question asks for barenames, I suggest that barenames are a mistake and not worth the effort of writing a complex decorator.  Barenames which are local are as bad as globals -- visually scopeless.

Comment: The main point was to leave the function pretty -- as simple as the design. The f.x solution found earlier seems better.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to save state between invocations of a function, you are almost always better off using a generator/coroutine or an object.  Since you want to use "bare" variable names, then you'll want the coroutine version.

```
# the coroutine holds the state and yields rather than returns values
def totalgen(x=0, y=0, z=0):
    while True:
       a, b, c = (yield x, y, z)
       x += a
       y += b
       z += c

# the function provides the expected interface to callers
def runningtotal(a, b, c, totalgen=totalgen()):
    try:
        return totalgen.send((a, b, c))    # conveniently gives TypeError 1st time
    except TypeError:
        totalgen.next()                    # initialize, discard results
        return totalgen.send((a, b, c))
```

The result is a function that accumulates totals of the three values passed to it, exactly as if it had static variables, but the accumulators are plain old local variables in what is essentially an infinite generator.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to encapsulate this idea into a decorator.

Comment: Probably not without a lot of bytecode hackery, and it would have difficulty if there was more than one `return` statement in a function even then. If I get some time, though, it seems like it would be a fun project.

Comment: ... on second thought, if I was gonna do some bytecode hackery I proabbly wouldn't take this route to implementing statics; there are simpler ways.

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak of [another anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1619225/58668):

```
def static(**kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        return type(func)(func.func_code, dict(func.func_globals, **kwargs))
    return decorator

message = "goodbye, world!"
@static(message="hello, world!")
def hello(): print message

hello()
```

I found it icky to override a builtin name with a function argument name, so I changed `**dict` into the more canonical `**kwargs`.  I also saved a few lines and IMO made the code cleaner by constructing a new dict with `dict(the_original, **the_updates)`.  Lastly I saved a few lines by accessing the function constructor via `type(func)` rather than an import---type and class objects are factory methods, so use them!

I also removed a `global` declaration.  This works as long as you don't rebind the variable, i.e. removing `global` in effect makes the pointer (but not the object) read-only.  If you use it this way, maybe `let` is a better name than `static` for the binding thus introduced.

Comment: I believe this gives unexpected results in the case of mutable globals. If the function prints global x, and x changes value between definition and call, the function will still print the old value of x, I believe, since you take a copy of the globals.

Comment: When trying to use this decorator in the scenario from the OP, I get `x += 1 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: good point about the globals!   As I stated, removing the `global` declaration works as long as the variable is read-only, which your example violates.  It might work if x has an __iadd__ method, though.

Comment: "My example" is actually the question, so it's strange to say it violates your answer.