# How to access a decorated method local variables ( locals() ) from inside a Python decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

Here's what I need:

Let's say I have this decorator:

```
def deco(func):
    def decoret(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__locals__) # I know __locals__ is not valid, but I need something like this
    return decoret

@deco
def func():
    test1 = 123
    test2 = 456

func()
```

I want to fetch a list of *all local variables* (as if I was calling locals() inside the function), so I would be able to access a **dictionary with test1 and test2 values** inside the decorator's *decoret* function.

I know I can do this by using Python inspect module, but I wasn't able to trace the right frame to get the function.

Also, I'm using Python 3.2 CPython.

Answer (score 3):

There **are** no locals in a function until it's executed. The only things available to you when it's decorated are what is there when it's defined.

```
d = 'd'
def a(d=d):
    b = 'b'
    c = 'c'

print a.__dict__
# {}
print a.b
# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'
print dir(a)
# Doesn't print anything
```

Comment: You're right, I got this wrong, because I was using it to make some magic with CherryPy and Tenjin ( actually to get rid on the need to return a dictionary to the template every time. ), I will find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found a way to circumvent and implement this using a trace from sys.

Take a look a this snippet:

```
def Property(function):
    keys = 'fget', 'fset', 'fdel'
    func_locals = {'doc':function.__doc__}
    def probeFunc(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'return':
            locals = frame.f_locals
            func_locals.update(dict((k,locals.get(k)) for k in keys))
            sys.settrace(None)
        return probeFunc
    sys.settrace(probeFunc)
    function()
    return property(**func_locals)
```

Took this from a snippet of code located at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410698/

Also, take a look on this stackoverflow topic: [Python: static variable decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611019/python-static-variable-decorator)

Comment: please... do not name functions with uppercase