# How to calculate the number of recursive call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

As ex. I write fibonancci code by recursion -

```
def fib(n):
    x = 0
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        print('computing : ', n) # this show the recursive call.
        x = x +1
        print('recursive call no total : ',x) # this show the how many number of recursive call.
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

but this print ,
recursive call no: 1
recursive call no: 1
and it's go on with 1 .

**theres some problem occur. I can't figure it out. The value of x doesn't increase's as it's not a iterative processes. But how i can increase the value of x through each recursive call ?**

Using a global variable , i tried to solve the ans . Code's may like below-

```
def fib(n):
    global numcalls
    numcalls += 1 #this will increment with every fib() call
    if n ==0 or n ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    print('numcalls =', numcalls)
```

Then calling the function with,
numcalls = 0
fib(5)

Is the code above ok ? If not , then suggest something abouts bugs .

Comment: make `x` an argument that defaults to `0` and then pass `x+1` to recursive calls.  That is what you do when you call a function and want it to have access to some specific information, you pass it as an argument.

Comment: or make a simple global variable and increment it at the beginning of the function

Comment: Can u show some ex how to pass x+1 to recursive call . I understand your first steps . So i can write def fib(n, x=0) . But how to do the nest steps ? @tadhg McDonald-Jensen

Comment: Yes you can make a global variable or even static variable decorator to solve your problem. But my point is you can decrement the number of recursive calls by adding a cache array which stores the result of recursive calls.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen your approach will not work in this case.
`def fib(n, x=0)` and increment x in body then at the time of calling you are passing same value of x to the two different branches of recursion which will print duplicate values instead of incremented values

Comment: do you want to keep track of the **total** calls during recursion or the **nested** number of calls?  I was interpreting "number of recursive calls" as how deep does the recursion go but that might not be what you were wanting.

Answer (score 2):

few ways of doing this

we can use counter as you tried with slight changes:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        print('computing : ', n)  # this show the recursive call.
        fib.x = fib.x + 1
        # this show the how many number of recursive call.
        print('recursive call no : ', fib.x)
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

fib.x = 0
fib(6)
```

we can also use decoration see [Python: static variable decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611019/python-static-variable-decorator)

A side effect of this is that you would manually have to reset `fib.x = 0` every time you call fib, one way of handling this within the function is by taking an extra argument that will only be specified by recursive calls to not reset `fib.x = 0`:

```
def fib(n, _from_user=True):
    if _from_user: #default was used so the call was from the user, set x to 0 now
        fib.x = 0
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        print('computing : ', n)  # this show the recursive call.
        fib.x = fib.x + 1
        # this show the how many number of recursive call.
        print('recursive call no : ', fib.x)
         #pass _from_user =  False for sub calls
        return fib(n - 1, False) + fib(n - 2, False)

fib(6)
```

Comment: Thanks . It's great .

Comment: The way it is written you will have to manually reset `fib.x = 0` before every call, may I make an edit that fixes this?  I don't want to unecessarily complicate your example if you are fine with resetting it every time but it would bug me.

Comment: You can fixs that if u like

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen go ahead

Comment: @user6359012 I added alternate version if you are interested. (I believe the edit and this comment will already ping Garima)

Answer (score 0):

Using a global variable , i tried to solve the ans . Code's may like below-

```
def fib(n):
    global numcalls
    numcalls += 1 #this will increment with every fib() call
    if n ==0 or n ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    print('numcalls =', numcalls)
```

Then calling the function with,
numcalls = 0
fib(5)

Is the code above ok ? If not , then suggest something abouts bugs .